Prove a set is not closed in topology
On the plane $\mathbb R^2$ with usual topology, let $F = ${$(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 3x - 2y <0, \, x + y = 0$}. Prove $F$ is not closed.
that's all i think is we need to prove there exists $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that  $(x,y)\in \overline F$ but $(x,y)\notin F$. 
we have $F = ${$(x, -x) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x  <0$}
Now consider the limit point $(0,0)$ then $(0,0) \notin F$
So F is not closed.

No you need to prove that there is an $(x,y)$ such that $(x,y)\in \overline F$ but $(x,y)\notin F.$

can you give me a hint?

Sketch $F$ and find a limit point of it that is not included.

You have some comments now. Could you edit your question to include your attempts with this newfound information?

@Malady i did. hope everyone will correct it

Convince me $(0,0)$ is a limit point.

@CyclotomicField Consider a sequence of points ${(x_n, -x_n)}$ in $F$ where $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Each $(x_n, -x_n) \in F$ because $x_n < 0$. As $x_n \to 0$, the points $(x_n, -x_n)$ approach the point $(0,0)$. The point $(0,0)$ is a limit point of the set $F$, because any neighborhood around $(0,0)$ will contain points of the form $(x, -x)$ with $x < 0$

This may be one of those situations where it's easier to prove that $U=\Bbb R^2 \setminus F$ is not open.  Can you show that $(0, 0)$ is not in the interior of $U$?  (Hint:  This is true because $(0, 0)$ is a limit point of $F$.)

@RobertShore i think this is good point. it's really easier to prove that U is not open

The usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ comes from the usual metric $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the metric induced by the Euclidean norm, i.e if $ x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $x = (x_1 , x_2)$ then $\parallel \ x \parallel = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}$ . I will denote $d(x,y) = \parallel \ x-y \parallel$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$
Now, every set is open (closed) in the metric space ($\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ iff is open (closed) in the topological space ($\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{T}_d)$, where $\mathcal{T}_d$ is the topology induced by the metric $d$ (the usual topology). A subset $A$ of a metric space is closed if and only if $A = \overline{A}$ . And the closure of a set in the metric space is the same that the closure in the topological space, but it is easier to determine (at least in this case) how the closure is in metric spaces because we have sequences. We have that $x \in \overline{A}$ iff there exists a sequence $\{ x_n \} \subseteq A$ such that $x_n \to x$. Coming back to your problem, it is obvious that $(0,0) \in \overline{F}$ because we have that the sequence $\{ (\frac{1}{n} , - \frac{1}{n}) \}$ is defined in $F$ and converges to $(0,0)$.
Due to $(0,0) \notin F$ we have that $F$ is not closed.
Note: For any metric space $(X,d)$ we say that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to some $x \in X$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(x,x_n) = 0$

You have the right idea. The point $o = 0 \times 0$ is a limit point of $F$ that is not contained in $F$. Clearly $o \notin F$ because $3 (0) - 2 (0) = 0$ is not less than $0$. To verify that $o$ is a limit point of $F$, we note that since $o \notin F$, it is enough to show that $o$ is contained in $\text{Cl} F$. Consider any basis element $B = B_d (o, \varepsilon)$, where $d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ is arbitrary. The point $p_\varepsilon = -\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \times \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ is clearly contained in $B$ since $d (o, p_\varepsilon) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \varepsilon < \varepsilon$. The point $p_\varepsilon$ is also contained in $F$, since $-\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon + \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon = 0$ and $3 \left( -\frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \right) - 2 \left( \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon \right) = -\frac{5}{2} \varepsilon < 0$. Since $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, this shows $o \in \text{Cl} F$, as desired.
